# Using Spring Statemachine we have difficulty changing some statuses

Tags: java, spring, spring-statemachine

Using Spring Statemachine I encountered a problem when changing the status:
PENDING is the initial status and we have a problem when changing from ARRIVED -> IN_PROGRESS and IN_PROGRESS -> COMPLETED.

It changes from ARRIVED to IN_PROGRESS only when it changes from PENDING to IN_PROGRESS.
We can change from IN_PROGRESS to COMPLETED, only if it changes from PENDING to COMPLETED.

```
/**
 * allow only the following transitions:
 *
 * PENDING -> WAITING or ARRIVED or NO_SHOW or USER_CANCELLED or TEAM_CANCELLED
 * WAITING -> ARRIVED or NO_SHOW
 * ARRIVED -> IN_PROGRESS or USER_CANCELLED or TEAM_CANCELLED
 * IN_PROGRESS ->  COMPLETED or USER_CANCELLED or TEAM_CANCELLED
 * COMPLETED -> no transition
 * USER_CANCELLED -> no transition
 * TEAM_CANCELLED -> no transition
 * NO_SHOW -> no transition
 */
```

possibly the configuration is not written correctly, can someone help us?

```
public void configure(final StateMachineStateConfigurer<Appointment.Status, Appointment.Status> states) throws Exception {
    states
            .withStates()
            .initial(Appointment.Status.PENDING)
            .states(EnumSet.allOf(Appointment.Status.class))
            .end(Appointment.Status.COMPLETED)
            .end(Appointment.Status.USER_CANCELLED)
            .end(Appointment.Status.TEAM_CANCELLED)
            .end(Appointment.Status.NO_SHOW);
}
```

```
public void configure(final StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<Appointment.Status, Appointment.Status> transitions) throws Exception {
    transitions
            .withExternal()
            .source(Appointment.Status.PENDING)
            .target(Appointment.Status.WAITING)
            .event(Appointment.Status.WAITING)
            .and()

            .withExternal()
            .source(Appointment.Status.PENDING)
            .target(Appointment.Status.ARRIVED)
            .event(Appointment.Status.ARRIVED)
            .and()

            .withExternal()
            .source(Appointment.Status.PENDING)
            .target(Appointment.Status.NO_SHOW)
            .event(Appointment.Status.NO_SHOW)
            .and()

            .withExternal()
            .source(Appointment.Status.PENDING)
            .target(Appointment.Status.USER_CANCELLED)
            .event(Appointment.Status.USER_CANCELLED)
            .and()

            .withExternal()
            .source(Appointment.Status.PENDING)
            .target(Appointment.Status.TEAM_CANCELLED)
            .event(Appointment.Status.TEAM_CANCELLED)
            .and()

            .withExternal()
            .source(Appointment.Status.WAITING)
            .target(Appointment.Status.ARRIVED)
            .event(Appointment.Status.ARRIVED)
            .and()

            .withExternal()
            .source(Appointment.Status.WAITING)
            .target(Appointment.Status.NO_SHOW)
            .event(Appointment.Status.NO_SHOW)
            .and()

            .withExternal()
            .source(Appointment.Status.ARRIVED)
            .target(Appointment.Status.IN_PROGRESS)
            .event(Appointment.Status.IN_PROGRESS)
            .and()

            .withExternal()
            .source(Appointment.Status.ARRIVED)
            .target(Appointment.Status.USER_CANCELLED)
            .event(Appointment.Status.USER_CANCELLED)
            .and()

            .withExternal()
            .source(Appointment.Status.ARRIVED)
            .target(Appointment.Status.TEAM_CANCELLED)
            .event(Appointment.Status.TEAM_CANCELLED)
            .and()

            .withExternal()
            .source(Appointment.Status.IN_PROGRESS)
            .target(Appointment.Status.COMPLETED)
            .event(Appointment.Status.COMPLETED)
            .and()

            .withExternal()
            .source(Appointment.Status.IN_PROGRESS)
            .target(Appointment.Status.USER_CANCELLED)
            .event(Appointment.Status.USER_CANCELLED)
            .and()

            .withExternal()
            .source(Appointment.Status.IN_PROGRESS)
            .target(Appointment.Status.TEAM_CANCELLED)
            .event(Appointment.Status.TEAM_CANCELLED);
}
```